why does containeros install 9 identical nameserver lines in resolv.conf?
I'm using a3-megagpu-8g instances with containeros for a gke cluster.
I believe it is version GOOGLE_RELEASE=17800.218.69 -- I recreated the node pool last night, so it should be current.
All versions of the OS I've used, make the DNS pods emit this kind of warning:
  Warning  DNSConfigForming  3m45s (x658 over 13h)  kubelet  Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 169.254.169.254 169.254.169.254 169.254.169.254

This, in turn, comes because the resolv.conf is generated as follows:
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
search us-west1-b.c.myproject.internal c.myproject.internal google.internal

All of those entries are redundant, AND there's more than the three that libc will actually deal with.
So, what component of the OS installer sets this up, and how can it be fixed?
(Again, this is a "standard" gke instance, where Google machine images are used.)
